# UML diagram of whole project in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, uml

How can I get a diagram of all classes in the project in intellij idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IntelliJ Ultimate Edition provides a diagram feature. More details [in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/working-with-diagrams.html).

If you are using IntelliJ Community Edition then you'll need to install a plugin such as:

- [Code Iris](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7324-code-iris)
- [Plant UML](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7017-plantuml-integration)

You can install these plugins from Preferences > Plugins ...

[image]